# url rewriting in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web

I have an asp.net C# website its url is like abc.com so when the website is loaded for the first time its url that appears is abc.com

But when i visit any other page and come backs to the home page its url become abc.com/home.aspx.

But i want it to be the same i.e abc.com means i want that the url that appears when the website is loaded for the first time and the url that appears for the home page after visiting any other page should be same.

I think url rewriting will be used here but i am not sure neither i have any knowledge how to use it so please help.

Comment: Sorry, but unreadible... Please format your question.

Answer (score 0):

By default this happens because of Default Document feature.. You can read about more from http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/default-documents link.

However once you open us the website abc.com and when you navigate it will surely show you the page name like www.abc.com/home.aspx

And thus what you are looking for seems not possible.

Comment: is it possible to redirect my abc.com/home.aspx page to abc.com so that my abc.com url always points to abc.com even if the url is abc.com/home.aspx

Comment: Well I don't not thing it should work. BTW can you please tell what is your purpose of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use link tag marking the canonical in the header of the page. So, in abc.com/home.aspx you can generate the link tag that tells crawlers that this is a duplicate of `abc.com` and dont crawl it.

Here are more reference regarding the same subject:
http://www.seomoz.org/blog/which-page-is-canonical
http://guyellisrocks.com/coding/adding-a-canonical-link-element-in-asp-net/

Comment: is it possible to show the url of abc.com/home.aspx as abc.com always

Comment: Yes, but you have to update all your site's links to make sure you dont have any link pointing to /home.aspx which is difficult than checking current request url and adding link tag for canonical url in header in master page.

Comment: I should say that the possibility shown by @PrashantLakhlani should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your home page when you visit abc.com it looks like your default page is set in place.

You can easily redirect user to "/" and it probably will be enough